# Start approval workflow on behalf of some one else

Tags: 2010, list, infopath, designer-workflow

I have created an approval workflow in SharePoint Designer, and the main workflow is working perfectly.

However I want a mail sent to the person mention in my form, if someone else starts the workflow.

I tried to insert a condition in the "Change the behavior of the overall task process", as you can see in the picture, but it just sends me the email.

Can some one tell me whats missing?

Thanks!

[image: "Change the behavior of the overall task process"]

Comment: I believe this might be an 'impersonation step', though I don't know more about it than that.  Though a quick Google search finds this link [link](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/31/impersonation-in-sharepoint-designer-2010-workflow/)

Answer (score 0):

I think two lines above the highlighted area in your screenshot the initiator receives an email without any conditions. Maybe this is what's causing this?